# mongodb php remote connexion

Tags: php, mongodb, steam

i have a script that work with Mongodb There is the code

```
  <?php
if(isset($_SESSION["steamid"])) {
include_once('steamauth/userInfo.php');
    $connection = new MongoClient();
    $collection = $connection->selectDB('admin')->selectCollection('site_users');
    $list = $collection->find();
    $steam_list = array();
    foreach($list as $key => $value){
        $steam_list[] = $value['steamid'];
    }

    if(!in_array($_SESSION['steamid'],$steam_list)){
        $collection->save(array('steamid' => $_SESSION['steamid'],'name' => $_SESSION['steam_personaname'],'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    }

?>
```

thats mean when user is logged in with his steam account connect to Mongodb
first question here the code try to connect to local Mongodb Server If yes i want to transform this connection into a remote connexion so ican use MongolabDb Hosting with it , waiting you helps guys thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**MongoCollection::find** method return [MongoCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php).

Need convert result. [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["steamid"])) {
    include_once('steamauth/userInfo.php');
    $connection = new MongoClient();
    $collection = $connection->selectDB('admin')->selectCollection('site_users');
    $cursor = $collection->find();
    $list=iterator_to_array($cursor)
    $steam_list = array();
    foreach($list as $key => $value){
        $steam_list[] = $value['steamid'];
    }

    if(!in_array($_SESSION['steamid'],$steam_list)){
        $collection->save(array('steamid' => $_SESSION['steamid'],'name' => $_SESSION['steam_personaname'],'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hello Mutlu for your answer but where is the remote connexion , i want to use external MongoDb Server (Mongolab)

Comment: `$connection=new MongoClient("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds057877.mongolab.com:<port>/<dbname>");`



[http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#connect-string](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#connect-string)